# Property x does not exist on type Function

Tags: typescript

I recently upgraded to using the NPM typings to replace the unsupported NuGet packages. The following code used to work fine:

```
interface Function
{
    /** Creates a function that calls the specified function using the specified "this" pointer. Useful in scenarios where we need to pass a function as  a callback, but specifying the value of "this".*/
    defer(thisArg: Object): Function;
}

Function.prototype.defer = function (thisArg: Object)
{
    var self = this;

    //return a function that calls the current function with the specific this argument
    return function()
    {
      self.call(thisArg)
   };
```

}

But now I'm getting the error `Property 'defer' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

The property DOES exist because I'm specifying it in the interface, but the compiler is still complaining. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not an answer, but isn't this what [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does?

Comment: look at the javascript output and make sure that the code that makes use of the `defer` function is being outputed *after* the definition. if the files are being output in the wrong order, then the use will occur before the definition, and you'll get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration merging rules for [global object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) are slightly changed(pay attention on example at the end of page). It should work this way.

```
declare global {
    interface Function
    {
        /** Creates a function that calls the specified function using the specified "this" pointer. Useful in scenarios where we need to pass a function as  a callback, but specifying the value of "this".*/
        defer(thisArg: Object): Function;
    }
}

Function.prototype.defer = function (thisArg: Object)
{
    var self = this;

    //return a function that calls the current function with the specific this argument
    return function()
    {
      self.call(thisArg)
   };
}
```